Which TV episode parodied the Mad Max guitarist?
I just watched Mad Max: Fury Road this weekend and the guitarist that is on the front of one of the rigs seemed familiar to me. Here's a picture from another question:

I haven't seen the original Mad Max movies but I assume the guitarist also makes an appearance there. I'm sure I've seen this parodied in an animated TV show. I thought it was The Simpsons but I've done some searching and can't find anything with a guitarist. It's not any of the Simpsons or South Park references from this page.
Anybody know which show/episode it is?

"I haven't seen the original Mad Max movies but I assume the guitarist also makes an appearance there." - No, as evident from this related question the new movie doesn't have anything to do with the previous movies, at least story-wise. And as evident from the answers to this related question he was purely invented for this movie. So if that was in any TV-show, it was surely not a parody of this particular movie (seeing how new it is) or any other Mad Max movie.

Which is not to say your question is invalid or ungrounded. There could still have been some similar scene somewhere (though, it's hard to pin down how similar is similar enough then), or they could both be based on some other common precedent or any other kind of mutual influence, only that it is highly unlikely that some other TV-show referenced exactly this scene, in which case the identification problem would be quite broad and unclear. (Or maybe the parody was entirely based on the trailer that was known earlier than the movie.)

No, I am thinking of something I saw at least 5 years ago, maybe 10, so it can't be from this particular film. It's possible I am thinking of something similar but not identical, e.g. a car chase scene with someone playing instruments.

In "The Running Man", the character Dynamo is belting out an opera while covered in Christmas lights and standing up in a car while chasing Arnold Schwarzenegger. It's not a cartoon but it's pretty similar (and awesome). https://youtu.be/dYoiQQB8Zps ..

@Brett I've never seen The Running Man, but that is the kind of thing it could be. I'm still sure it's animated, and with a guitar.

Since Doof Warrior and his "Marshall stacks" were not in any prior movie(s), there could be no parody of it, so the question cannot really be answered.
However, a couple things come to mind that are 1) animated; 2) funny; and 3) metal.
Brutal Legend trailer
Dethklok Metaloocalypse
Brett from American Dad

And then there's a Rammstein live performance
